# Abort/ignore parameterized test in JUnit 5

Tags: junit5, parameterized

I have some parameterized tests

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvFileSource(resources = "testData.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
public void testExample(String parameter, String anotherParameter) {

    // testing here
}
```

In case one execution fails, I want to ignore all following executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no built-in mechanism to do this. The following does work, but is a bit hackish:

```java
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class Test {

    boolean skipRemaining = false;
    
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvFileSource(resources = "testData.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
    void test(String parameter, String anotherParameter) {
        Assumptions.assumeFalse(skipRemaining);
        try {
            // testing here
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            skipRemaining = true;
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

In contrast to a failed assertion, which marks a test as failed, an assumption results in an abort of a test. In addition, the [lifecycle](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle) is switched from per method to per class:

> When using this mode, a new test instance will be created once per test class. Thus, if your test methods rely on state stored in instance variables, you may need to reset that state in `@BeforeEach` or `@AfterEach` methods.

Depending on how often you need that feature, I would rather go with a [custom extension](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions).

Comment: Looks like the whole test class is newly initialized after each single test, thus in case the exception is caught and failure is set to "true", this vanishes when the next execution of the test is due.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann totally forgot about this, fixed the answer accordingly.